# Word Task Pane Apps - SharePoint Connection

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, database-connection, office-js

I want to input data from a SharePoint list into a Word document using a Task Pane App.  I am creating the app in Visual Studio.  When I click on Tools/Add SharePoint connection, but I get a message that says that I don't have SharePoint Foundation installed on my system. I have Visual Studio on my computer and my SharePoint site is in the cloud, so I don't see how SharePoint Foundation would be on my system in this context.

Any suggestions as to how to connect to the list or where to go for instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: I press Tools/Add SharePoint Connection in Visual Studio 15 and I get a message saying that the required version of SharePoint Foundation or Server is not installed on my system, which does not make sense to me because my copy of SharePoint is in the cloud. Then I get the server name from Access, press Tools/Connect to Server I get a message that says it cannot connect to "eastus-2a", which is not the server name that I typed in.

Comment: I read the links suggested by jayesh, but they seem to be dealing with using JavaScript from my SharePoint site to access lists on the site. I am trying to create an app for 3d parties that can access lists on my site. These are static lists of things like zip codes and cities, so there is no need to be able to edit them, just access the information.

Answer (score 1):

you can create sharepoint hosted app, please refer these link :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/01/30/build-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-to-access-list-data-in-your-host-web-using-the-rest-api-in-10-easy-steps/

Also refer these for working with sharepoint list data: 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2013/09/05/working-with-sharepoint-list-data-odata-rest-and-javascript/